# 別セグメントからの SSH 接続ができない

Tags: centos, network, ssh

お世話になっております。
別セグメントからのSSHの通信ができない状態です。
アドバイス等ご教授いただければ幸いです。

サーバー
CentOS 6.10
192.168.120.2
openssl 1.0.1e

ルーター
RTX1210
LAN1　192.168.10.1 →DHCPにてwindows端末①
LAN2　192.168.120.1 サーバー②
　＊ルーティングは何も設定していません。
　　デフォルトでは全開放とのこと（サポートセンターにログを送り確認済み、サーバーの設定の問題とのこと）

windows端末①→サーバー②の通信
・ping→OK
・Apache→OK
・SSH→NG

SELINUXをdisabled
iptablesを落とした状態でもSSHはつながらず接続が拒否されます。

```
> ssh -p 22 root@192.168.120.2
ssh: connect to host 192.168.120.2 port 22: Connection refused
```

同じセグメントだと問題なく接続されます。どこを設定すればいいのでしょう？

何卒よろしくお願いします。

ご指摘ありましたので `/etc/hosts.deny` と `/etc/hosts.allow` も確認しましたが、どちらもコメント行のみで特に設定はされていませんでした。

Comment: 「SSHはつながらず接続が拒否」の際、具体的にはどのようなエラーメッセージが表示されますか？

Comment: お使いのRTX1210はVPNルータのようですね。VPNルータは拠点(本店と支店など）にそれぞれ設置して、拠点のLANどうしを同じネットワークセグメントであるかのように機能させるといった用途（拠点間接続）に使われる機器です。
そのため、様々な設定ができるようになっているのが普通です。

質問者が使っているRTX1210は、どのように設定されているのでしょうか？
まずRTX1210のマニュアルをよく読んで、質問者が望んでいるような使い方ができるかどうか、できるとしたら設定をどのようにすればよいか、といった事を確認するのが良いと思います。

Comment: hidezzz様
下記のようなメッセージです
>ssh -p 22 root@192.168.120.2
ssh: connect to host 192.168.120.2 port 22: Connection refused

Comment: Fumu 7 様
IPを設定しただけです。
マニュアルを確認し、サポートセンターにサーバーの設定の問題と指摘を受けたうえで質問しています

Comment: DHCP で IP アドレスを割り当てているのはこのルータですか？それとも別に DHCP サーバが存在しますか？ [マニュアル (PDF) の P.367 辺り](http://www.rtpro.yamaha.co.jp/RT/manual/rtx1210/Webgui.pdf) が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: >DHCP で IP アドレスを割り当てているのはこのルータですか？
はい
>マニュアル (PDF) の P.367 辺り が参考になるかもしれません
YAMAHAのサポートセンターにログを送付したのですが、つながるはずでサーバーを見直せとのことでした。
やはりルータを見たほうがいいでしょうか？

Comment: 「iptablesを落とした状態」と書かれていますが、具体的にはどうされたのでしょうか？

Comment: metropolis 様
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
を実行しました。